# The Weil restriction of a simple algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Let $F$ be a number field, $G$ an $F$-simple affine algebraic group.
Then is the Weil restriction $\operatorname{Res}_{F/\mathbb{Q}} G$ $\mathbb{Q}$-simple?
I couldn’t find any references.

Comment: The Weil restriction of $\mathbf{A}^1_F$ is $\mathbf{A}^d_{\mathbf{Q}}$ where $d = [F:\mathbf{Q}]$.

Comment: @HYL The additive group is not a simple algebraic group (it is not semisimple, it is not reductive, … ).

Comment: See Section 6.21 (ii) of the paper "Groupes Reductifs" by Borel and Tits.

Comment: @naf Thank you, but I don’t understand French, so I culdn’t get it. Is it simple?

Comment: Yes, it is simple.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428933/the-weil-restriction-of-a-simple-algebraic-group#comment1103770_428933), there's so much good math about algebraic groups in [Borel and Tits - Groupes réductifs](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1965__27__55_0) and the [compléments](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1972__41__253_0) that it's worth learning enough French to read it.  Reading mathematical French is very easy compared to reading general French or math in another language, at least for me as a very monoglot English speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, the answer is yes. Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group (meaning $F$-simple) over $F$.

Assume first that $F$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $(\mathrm{Res}_{F/\mathbb{Q}}G)_{F}\simeq G_{1}\times\cdots\times G_{r}$, where the $G_{i}$ are the conjugates of $G$ under $\mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$. If $H$ is a smooth connected normal algebraic subgroup of $\mathrm{Res}_{F/\mathbb{Q}}G$, then $H_{F}$ is a product of a certain number of the $G_{i}$ (Milne, Algebraic Groups, 21.51), which is stable under the Galois action. But $\mathrm{Gal}% (F/\mathbb{Q})$ acts transitively on the set of $G_{i}$, and so $H=\mathrm{Res}_{F/\mathbb{Q}}G$.

In the general case, the same argument works if $G$ is geometrically simple. If not, then we may suppose that $G=\mathrm{Res}_{F^{\prime}/F}G^{\prime}$ with $G^{\prime}$ geometrically simple (ibid. 24.3) and apply the argument to $G^{\prime}$.

This argument fails for algebraic groups like $\mathbb{G}_{a}^{n}$ because for them the decomposition into simple objects is not unique.

Note that the proof only uses standard properties of semisimple groups, for which I gave a modern reference. I don't understand the comment of LSpice.

Comment: Milne is a fantastic reference for a lot of things, but, as @naf [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1103368), I think [Borel and Tits - Groupes réductifs](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1965__27__55_0), and, if I remember correctly, the [compléments article](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1972__41__253_0) has more to say about Weil restriction than Milne.  (But the OP [doesn't understand French](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1103770), so Milne is probably a better reference!)

Comment: I in no way meant to play games or criticise your answer, which I thought was a good answer and which I upvoted; I only meant to add additional context. I'm sorry for whatever part of what I did made you feel unwelcome, or that your answer was unwelcome. I hope you will roll back to the very useful [original version](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/432303/1) of your answer, or, if it is tolerable, my [edit of it](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/432303/2) to add a link to the comment you referenced.

Comment: @anon Welcome to MathOverflow! Editing others' posts to improve the Latex, add links, etc. is a normal thing here. If you don't like others improving your posts, you can ask them not to, but please don't remove valuable content you've posted. I've rolled back your post to an earlier version. You're welcome to edit it further, but please don't destroy it.